# How do I make Devise redirect to the correct root after signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models with Devise. The one I'm working on now has `match '/therapists' => "api/therapists#index", as: :therapist_root` in `config/routes.rb`, so I sort of assumed it would redirect to `therapist_root` after therapist signup. Instead it goes to `/`. What magic do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of devise, you first have to generate the controller for the specific model using

```
rails g devise:controller <scope> (replace scope by the model name)
```

Then you have to define a **create** action and in that action, add

```
redirect_to(therapist_url)
```

in the block where signup is successful (something like `if @therapist.save` or so). Then in the **routes**, make the `devise_for` for the particular model to

```
devise_for <model>, controllers: { <controller>: '<controller>' } 
(replace <model> by name of model and <controller> by name of controller)
```

Comment: There should be a better way to do this. The Devise registrations controller does a pretty good job and I wouldn't like to override it unless absolutely necessary. In the worst case I can override `after_sign_up_path_for`, but I was wondering if there was anything more elegant.

Comment: Yep. This is a messy way. I do not know of another way. Sorry